# Moving files with a batch script started by PHP event?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I currently have some kind of a problem with a combination of a batch and a php script I want to move files automaticly with on my Windows machine.
So I installed xampp, made apache run at a service and so on.  I created a batch script as well which should move files from one location to another.
Running this batch script on the computer works perfectly fine, however starting it from a php script does not work.
Killing a process or shutting down the machine with this kind of method will work, but moving files from one location to another doesn't work. It seems like the move command is simply skipped, since commands in front and behind it will work.

```
<?php
exec('"C:\Users\bob\Desktop\kill.bat"', $output, $return);
foreach($output as $line){
echo $line."<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Tha batch file is like:

```
taskkill /IM test.exe /T /F
move C:\path\to\stuff\*.avi Z:\path\to\destination\
shutdown -s
```

Remember: This problem just seems to appear when the script is started via php. Startig it by hand will make it run properly!

Comment: does your webserver user account have access to the `bob` folders? I'm guessing not.